ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.2.jar
ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add home/areaapache/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.2.jar \
  to Spark environment

import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, explode, to_date, first, last, max, min, avg,     sum, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType, DoubleType, LongType,   IntegerType
import time
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


kafka_topic_name = "finnhub_data"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"

mysql_host_name = "localhost"
mysql_port_no = "3306"
mysql_database_name = "finnhub_processed"
mysql_driver_class = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"  # Cập nhật driver class
mysql_table_name = "processed_trade_data"
mysql_user_name = "tuanle"
mysql_password = "123456"
mysql_jdbc_url = f"jdbc:mysql://{mysql_host_name}:{mysql_port_no}/{mysql_database_name}"

cassandra_host_name = "localhost"
cassandra_port_no = "9042"
cassandra_keyspace_name = "finnhub_data"
cassandra_table_name = "raw_trade_data"

spark_jar = "file:///home/tuanle/areaapache/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/jars"
def save_to_cassandra(df, epoch_id):
    logger.info(f"Saving batch {epoch_id} to Cassandra")
    
    df_to_save = df.select(
        col("symbol"),
        (col("trade_time") / 1000).cast("timestamp").alias("trade_time"),
        col("price"),
        col("volume"),
        col("conditions"),
        col("company")
    )
    
    df_to_save.write \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .mode("append") \
        .options(table=cassandra_table_name, keyspace=cassandra_keyspace_name) \
        .save()
    
    logger.info(f"Batch {epoch_id} saved to Cassandra successfully")

def process_and_save_to_mysql(spark):
    logger.info("Starting to process data from Cassandra and save to MySQL")

    df_cassandra = spark.read \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .options(table=cassandra_table_name, keyspace=cassandra_keyspace_name) \
        .load()

    df_processed = df_cassandra \
        .withColumn("trade_date", to_date(col("trade_time"))) \
        .groupBy("symbol", "trade_date") \
        .agg(
            first("price").alias("open_price"),
            last("price").alias("close_price"),
            max("price").alias("high_price"),
            min("price").alias("low_price"),
            avg("price").alias("avg_price"),
            sum("volume").alias("total_volume")
        ) \
        .withColumn("processed_time", lit(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

    df_processed.write \
        .jdbc(url=mysql_jdbc_url,
            table=mysql_table_name,
            mode="append",
            properties={
                "user": mysql_user_name,
                "password": mysql_password,
                "driver": mysql_driver_class
            })

    logger.info("Data processed and saved to MySQL successfully")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Data Processing Application Started ...")

    # Khởi tạo Spark Session và định nghĩa cấu hình cần thiết
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka, Cassandra, and MySQL") \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", True) \
        .config("spark.jars", f"{spark_jar}/jsr305-3.0.0.jar,{spark_jar}/spark-cassandra-connector_2.13-3.5.1.jar,{spark_jar}/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.2.jar,{spark_jar}/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.2.jar,file:///usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar,{spark_jar}/kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar") \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4) \
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandra_host_name) \
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandra_port_no) \
        .config("spark.sql.mysql.host", mysql_host_name) \
        .config("spark.sql.mysql.port", mysql_port_no) \
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "60000") \
        .master("local[4]") \
        .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    logger.info("Spark Session initialized successfully")

    finnhub_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()

    logger.info("Printing Schema of finnhub_df:")
    finnhub_df.printSchema()

    finnhub_schema = StructType([
        StructField("data", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("c", ArrayType(StringType())),
            StructField("p", DoubleType()),
            StructField("s", StringType()),
            StructField("t", LongType()),
            StructField("v", IntegerType()),
            StructField("company", StringType())
        ]))),
        StructField("type", StringType())
    ])

    finnhub_df1 = finnhub_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
    finnhub_df2 = finnhub_df1.select(from_json(col("value"), finnhub_schema).alias("finnhub"), "timestamp")
    finnhub_df3 = finnhub_df2.select("finnhub.data", "timestamp")
    finnhub_df4 = finnhub_df3.select(explode("data").alias("trade_data"), "timestamp")
    finnhub_df5 = finnhub_df4.select(
        col("trade_data.s").alias("symbol"),
        col("trade_data.t").alias("trade_time"),
        col("trade_data.p").alias("price"),
        col("trade_data.v").alias("volume"),
        col("trade_data.c").alias("conditions"),
        col("trade_data.company").alias("company"),
        col("timestamp")
    )

    query_cassandra = finnhub_df5 \
        .writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .foreachBatch(save_to_cassandra) \
        .start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(300)  # Wait for 5 minutes
            process_and_save_to_mysql(spark)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.info("Application interrupted. Stopping streams...")
        query_cassandra.stop()
        spark.stop()
        logger.info("Application stopped successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        query_cassandra.stop()
        spark.stop()
        logger.info("Application stopped due to an error")

File "/home/tuanle/apachearea/software/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, \
  in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.load. : \
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSourceProvider$$validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:338) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.sourceSchema(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:71) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:233) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:118) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:118) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:36) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:169) \
         at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:145) \
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) \
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) \
         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) \
         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374) \
         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) \
         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) \
         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) \
         at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182) \
         at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106) \
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) \
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less \
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) \
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) \
         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) \
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) \
         ... 20 more
2024-09-26 22:42:24,971 - INFO - Closing down clientserver connection`

I don't know why I have already downloaded all the necessary jar files that match the version.
Then save it to the jars folder but spark still can't find it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's your Scala version that's wrong.
For example, you might have Spark for Scala 2.12, but your kafka package is compiled for 2.13, which is not compatible. You also do not need both Kafka streaming and kafka sql jar files to be loaded to the same app; you're only using one of them.
Same problem applies to Cassandra connector.
This is a common reason for this message in the stacktrace java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less

Oh, thanks you very much.

If this answers your question, feel free to accept the answer using the checkmark next to the post
